# Apply coupon code only for specific category

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes

I am working on magento 1.9.1.

I am offering **50 % off** if customer add product to cart from particular category (Say Category A).

In the cart page, the customer have added other category products too.

Ex:

```
Product 1 - Category A, Product 2 - Category C, Product 3 - Category B
```

When we apply coupon code, its applying for all products in cart.

But, the coupon must not apply **if Other category products are added** (Say Category B & C).[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate the conditions into the  "Apply the rile to cart items matching....".
it clearly states in the title "leave blank for all items".