# Coupon Code Discount for Product in Certain Categories

Tags: magento2, discount, coupon-codes

I'm trying to create a coupon code that will apply a discount to an item in a cart if it is in a certain category but won't discount other items that are also in the cart.

I tested out what I created and the discount didn't apply when I had an item in the cart that wasn't in one of the categories but when I added an item that was in a category it applied the discount to everything in the cart.

This is what I have set up so far:
[image: Conditions]

[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99110/apply-coupon-code-only-for-specific-category?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use "contains" or "is one of" and see if that works.

[image]

Comment: I changed it to both and tested and it is still doing the same thing, it is taking the discount off the subtotal and I am wanting the discount only to be applied to the items that are in the categories I've chosen.

Comment: @AnaS did you manage to get any workaround or Magento 2 patches for this ?